# Como hacer un ArrayList y que como resultado del programa me los pinte como tabla!

Tags: java

tengo un programa en java usando ArrayList, el detalle que quiero como resultado me los pinte como si fuera una tabla es decir:

```
Nombre|ApellidoMaterno |ApellidoPaterno 
Juan  |Bustamante      |Solis
```

Y asi sucesivamente

Este es mi codigo:

```
public class Empleado1 {

    public int IdEmpleado;
    public String Nombre;
    public String ApellidoP;
    public String ApellidoM;

    public Empleado1(int IdEmpleado, String Nombre, String ApellidoP, String ApellidoM){
        this.IdEmpleado = IdEmpleado;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.ApellidoP = ApellidoP;
        this.ApellidoM = ApellidoM;

    }

    //Metodo para imprimir el array de Empleado

    static void imprimeArrayEmpleados(Empleado1[] array){
        for(int i=0; i< array.length; i++){
            System.out.println("ID " + array[i].IdEmpleado + " Nombre: " + array[i].Nombre + "|" + "Apellido Paterno: " + array[i].ApellidoP + "|" + "Apellido Materno: "  + array[i].ApellidoM);

        }

    }



}
```

Y esta es la clase main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Empleado1[] arrayEmpledos = new Empleado1[11];
        arrayEmpledos[0] = new Empleado1(1, " Armando ", "Palafox", "Martinez");
        arrayEmpledos[1] = new Empleado1(2, " Juan Jose", "Bustamante", "Solis");
        arrayEmpledos[2] = new Empleado1(3, " Armando ", "Palafox", "Martinez");
        arrayEmpledos[3] = new Empleado1(4, " Juan Jose", "Bustamante", "Solis");
        arrayEmpledos[4] = new Empleado1(5, " Armando ", "Palafox", "Martinez");
        arrayEmpledos[5] = new Empleado1(6, " Juan Jose", "Bustamante", "Solis");
        arrayEmpledos[6] = new Empleado1(7, " Armando ", "Palafox", "Martinez");
        arrayEmpledos[7] = new Empleado1(8, " Juan Jose", "Bustamante", "Solis");
        arrayEmpledos[8] = new Empleado1(9, " Armando ", "Palafox", "Martinez");
        arrayEmpledos[9] = new Empleado1(10, " Juan Jose", "Bustamante", "Solis");
        arrayEmpledos[10] = new Empleado1(13, " Armando ", "Palafox", "Martinez");


        imprimeArrayEmpleados(arrayEmpledos);

    }
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar a brindarme un tip de como podria hacerlo, saludos amigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso lo puedes lograr utilizando la clase [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

```
System.out.println("ID  |Nombre         |Apellido paterno |Apellido materno");
System.out.println("----|---------------|-----------------|---------------");
for(int i=0; i< arrayEmpledos.length; i++){
    System.out.println(new Formatter().format("%-4s", arrayEmpledos[i].id)
                  +""+ new Formatter().format("%-16s", "| " + arrayEmpledos[i].nombre)
                     + new Formatter().format("%-16s", "| " + arrayEmpledos[i].apellidoP)
                     + new Formatter().format("%-16s", "  | " + arrayEmpledos[i].apellidoM));
}
```

En funcionamiento de la clase Formatter es sencillo, el primer parámetro del constructor recibe la expresión que se utiliza para formatear el texto y el segundo parámetro el texto a formatear. En este caso la expresión es simple `"%-4s"`: `-` alinea el texto a la izquierda; `4` numero de espacios que tendrá el texto; `s` se puede aplicar a cualquier tipo de argumento (texto, numérico, flotante, etc).

Comment: Hola David Minaya muchas gracias por la ayuda, solo una duda, aquí por que esta cambiando a %-16s??

Comment: @JuanJoséBustamante El numero indica el numero de espacios que tendrá el texto, a el id le asigno 4 espacios y a los demás 16 espacios.

Comment: @JuanJoséBustamante Si una respuesta te fue de utilidad recuerda dar las gracias de manera constructiva, como marcando la respuesta como **aceptada ✔**, dando un **voto a favor ⏏**, o **ambas ✔⏏**, tal como se explica en el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio.

Comment: Perfecto, si salio lo que esperaba, solo un pequeño detalle, por ejm las columnas se repiten en cada lista, eso hay alguna manera de corregirlo y a su vez en el resultado los titulos de las celdas salen abajo de los registros

Comment: Listo amigo ya te calificate, muchas gracias

Comment: @JuanJoséBustamante no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres lograr, pero, solo tienes que jugar con las sentencias que imprimen el texto y de seguro logras cualquier cosa que te imagines. Esto mucha veces se trata de ensayo y error.

Comment: Si es lo que voy hacer en jugar con los resultado, gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar algo como esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.format("%10s%20s%20s", "NOMBRE", "APELLIDO PATERNO", "APELLIDO MATERNO");
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            String nombre = "Juan"+i;
            String apellidoP = "Lopez"+i;
            String apellidoM = "Lopez"+(i+1);
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.format("%10s%10s%20s", nombre, apellidoP, apellidoM);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
```

Te dejo la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta amigo, lo voy a realizar como me lo planteas, saludos.